# Determining angles on an SVG path between two lines

Tags: javascript, math, svg

I'm trying to make my robot follow a path that is a drawn SVG path on a webpage.  To keep it simple, assume that the SVG Is like so:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path id="path" d="M 100 100 L 300 300 L 100 500 z">
</svg>
```

Which makes a triangle.

The robot will start at 100, 100.  The goal is to get him to move to 300, 300, but I don't know how to get the angle that the robot needs to turn from 100, 100 to start moving towards 300, 300.

I've included a poorly put together image showing the angle I'm trying to get.  Although this is just a simple example that's obviously 90 degrees, I'm using this to figure out how to do it on more complex drawings.

I'm writing this all in javascript.

[image: Badly drawn angle image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calculating the angle between two points use **arctan(slope)**, where slope = **(P2y - P1y) / (P2x - P1x)**

Where:

```
P2y = coordinate "y" of point 2
P1y = coordinate "y" of point 1
P2x = coordinate "x" of point 2
P1x = coordinate "x" of point 1
```

Be aware of the signs (+ or -) that the arctan function returns, you must use common sense and logic for this.

Also be aware that your path is using absolute coordinates (L), it means that the point 3 will have the same "x" coordinate as the point 1 and not as shown in the picture, when it's more likely relative coordinate (l)

Comment: Good catch.  That last one should be 500, 100, not 100,500.